# How to access individual bar items in a bar graph - Helpful from accessibility point of view too [MPAndroidChart ]

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, mpandroidchart, screen-readers

I am using MPAndroidChart Library(https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to show bar items.

Currently when I am trying to get focus on each individual item in the bar graph, I am not able to do so, rather getting the focus on the whole chart.
I am trying to access the individual items or the child views inside the bar graph and trying to get focus on each item so that accessibility can work on items separately.

When I am trying to look in the layout inspector as well, not seeing the focus going in the individual items and there are no view identifiers too for each item. Just for the whole graph.

This is how my bar graph looks.

[[image: Bar graph]

[image: Layout Inspector]

This is how I have implemented in the code

This is the xml

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"/>
```

Also in the kotlin file,

```
`private fun init() {
        binding = ViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)

        with(binding.chart) {
            // Disable all the default cruft
            setDrawBorders(false)
            setPinchZoom(false)
            
    // THIS IS HOW I AM ACHIEVING THE ACCESSIBILITY READING FOR THE WHOLE GRAPH
            contentDescription = "This is a bar chart accessibility testing example."

            isHighlightPerDragEnabled = false
            isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
            legend.isEnabled = false

            // Precisely fit the bars to the screen
            setFitBars(true)
        }
}`
```

Has someone been able to achieve this?

I tried getting the view Identifier for each item but was not able to do so.
Tried to check in the library to somehow request focus at child elements but was not able to do so.

So trying to figure out how can I achieve.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/pull/4936 and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.12442 (pdf).

Comment: Hi @slugolicious, First of all thanks for your reply.
yes I have seen this PR and also have tested the same with https://github.com/AppDevNext/AndroidChart/pull/112 library where it was merged.
But the problem is same that PR only reads accessibility on the whole graph.
I need it on individual bar items.

Comment: Maybe someone knows better, but unfortunately I don't think it's possible, since the bars and other chart elements are not individual views, but just drawn on the chart canvas within the single chart view. You might be able to use the [MarkerView](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView) feature to get it to work (e.g. add accessibility info on a custom marker view) - however that requires the user to click on the bar first to show the view.

Comment: did anyone find any solution for this? as there are no options for set accessibility on individual views as per the open PR.  @TylerV , Hiten !

Comment: @Radhey Haven't been able to yet. On the other hand have made the stakeholders understood the issue and may have to work on custom bar graphs in the future.